# Why timedeltas can't be multiplied/divided in NumPy?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I'm new to `NumPy` and I'm trying to compute some simple statistics like the `median` or the `stddev`.

One of the "columns" I want to explore is a time difference (being its type the `timedelta64` `NumPy` type), but I can't apply those statistical `ufuncs` directly:

```
----> 1 age_request.std()

TypeError: ufunc 'divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be 
safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'
```

**Why is this happening?**

I know i should look into `Pandas`, but first I would like to familiarize myself with `NumPy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).  It lists the operations you can perform on a `timedelta` object.  Division is done like so:

```
t1 = t2 // i
```

Be aware that this computes the floor and throws away any remainder.

As far as I know, you can only do these operations on a `timedelta` object.  Though perhaps I am wrong and you can use `numpy` operations.

I would suggest converting the `timedelta` object to microseconds and then doing your division, standard deviation, median, etc:

```
tdMicrosecs = td.microseconds + 1000.0 * td.seconds + 86400000000.0 * td.days
tdQuotient = tdMicrosecs / i
```

(I should add, though, that I'm not entirely sure what the maximum integer value is that python can store and if `tdMicrosecs` could exceed it.)

Comment: Or in Python >= 2.7, use timedelta.to_seconds(), which gives you a floating point number of seconds.

Comment: On Python 3.3 use timedelta.total_seconds() instead